# What is the reference vector in OpenCV for 3D rotation?

Tags: opencv, math, camera, geometry, camera-calibration

I am working with the `Calib3D` module of OpenCV to do 3D reconstruction of a scene, and I am attempting to understand how OpenCV handles the extrinsic calibration of a camera, in particular the rotation. I understand that OpenCV uses a Rodrigues vector, i.e. a vector that defines the rotation axis through the direction that it is pointing in and the rotation angle by how much a vector shall be rotated around the axis through the length of the Rodrigues vector (c.f., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)).

To illustrate, here's how I imagine the situation:

[image: Visualization of the geometric situation]

In other words: There is some reference vector v_ref (red in the image) and the vector v_cam (blue) that points in the direction that the camera is pointing in. In this example, there's an angle of 75.96° between the two. The Rodrigues vector v_Rodigues is therefore calculated by first calculating the normalized cross-product between v_Ref and v_cam and then multiply that by the angle to get it to the appropriate length.

From this, I have two questions:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. What does OpenCV use as v_Ref?

**Edit:** Since the question seems to cause some misunderstandings:
I effectively have the following situation:
I measured the position of my camera using a total station.
This means that I have a good estimate for the location of the camera and the camera's forward vector `v_Cam`.
However, OpenCV expects a Rodrigues vector (`v_Rodrigues` in the figure), not the camera's forward vector `v_Cam`.
I am therefore trying to calculate `v_Rodrigues` from my `v_Cam`, which, as has been pointed out in the comments, only works if I know `v_Ref`.
And that is the reason why I am trying to find out what OpenCV uses as the definition of `v_Ref`.

I think that I have a good understanding of how OpenCV's camera and world coordinate systems are defined, I am merely missing the definition of `v_Ref`.

Comment: yes. axis of rotation is perpendicular to both vectors. cross product is suitable. angle can be calculated with cross product or dot product, and then some trig function. with a little algebra and judicious application or normalization (or lack thereof), the whole expression can probably be simplified greatly. I'm not mathy enough to dare write an answer.

Comment: What is `v_Ref` depends on the context, and you are already knowing what is represented by the `v_Rodrigues` here.
So, think about no rotation situation. The `v_Ref` equals the `v_Cam` on this situation. This may be answer for the your question 2.

Comment: In other words, considering about when the rotation is represented with another way. e.g. When 3x3 matrix `R` used, the rotation can be described as `v_result = R * v_src`. And it looks like that you are asking "what is the `v_src` ?".
If so, this question seems a bit nonsensical because it should be already defined in actual problem/context.

Comment: Well, `v_Ref` is arbitrary. It could be `(0, 0, 1)` or `(1, 0, 0)` or any other value, the math would still work, as long as `v_Rodrigues` is adapted accordingly. My question is therefore what the value of `v_Ref` is that is used specifically in OpenCV, because I even tried to dig into the source code of OpenCV but found nothing.

Comment: Also, while I do have a more or less accurate measurement of `v_Cam` (I measured the camera with a total station), I know that the values of my `v_Rodrigues` are garbage, which is why I am attempting to find `v_Ref` such that I can compute `v_Rodrigues` from my `v_Cam`

Comment: a rotation is defined by an angle around _one_ vector, which is the axis of rotation. your talk about "v_ref", or _two vectors_, makes no sense to me. I see no reason to ask for such a thing. -- perhaps you need to know about the coordinate systems of opencv. looking at screen/looking out of a camera: X right, Y down, Z far (optical axis). -- don't think of introducing your sought-after "v_ref" artificially. there is no justification for it.

Comment: e.g. at optimizing extrinsic parameter, the order of process will be :
**First, some value of the rotation is given**, then the given rotation is used to rotate something(and modify the value of the rotation based on evaluation of the rotated result, and back to the first step).
So, if you are reading such process code, you will not be able to find `v_Ref` used to calculate the rotation.

Comment: If you have only 1 vector (you written as "my v_Cam"), information will not be enough to define the rotation(: relative orientation between some two 3D-coordinate-systems), Because you can not constrain the angle around the `v_Cam`.

Comment: I really don't understand what is unclear about my question. Please have a detailed look at the figure which should explain the situation: Yes, the rotation is defined around **one** vector, `v_Rodrigues`. And the rotation rotates something (`v_Ref`) around that rotation axis. The resulting vector of that rotation is called in my example `v_Cam`. Does it now make sense why three vectors are involved @ChristophRackwitz ?

Comment: And @fana I know that one vector is not enough, which is why I am trying to find OpenCV's definition of `v_Ref` :)

Comment: why did you not react to my description of *coordinate frames*? why do you think that's irrelevant? should I have saved the effort?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz We seem to misunderstand each other: I did react to your comment and your effort is much appreciated :) I'll add more context to the question to hopefully clarify what I am trying to do, let me know if it is still unclear :)

Comment: So, your situation is... you want to use some OpenCV function which requires Rodrigues vector as argument, and now you are already knowing "camera's forward vector".
But, I think, actually, you are knowing or assuming more. e.g. "Camera rotation is only Pitch and Yaw : No Roll".
If your are in such condition, what you really need will be "How to get Rodrigues vector from known Rotation(e.g. Rotation Matrix)", not `v_Ref`.

Comment: i.e. if you know all three (two is enough) basis vectors of the camera coordinate system as values on some coordinate system(e.g. called as "World Coordinate System")... searching about "How to obtain the rotation axis and rotation angle from a rotation matrix" will be a good way.

Comment: Again, I know how that works, but even using a rotation matrix and deriving a Rodrigues vector from it still poses the same question: What does OpenCV consider to be a zero-rotation? Is it with the camera pointing up? Is it with the camera pointing along the x-Axis? Is it with the camera pointing along the y-Axis or is it anything else? Only if that zero-Rotation or `v_Ref` is known can a rotation be defined, no matter if it is represented using a rotation matrix, a Rodrigues vector or even Euler-Angles or a Quaternion.

Comment: this will be my last comment. I quote: *"looking at screen/looking out of a camera: X right, Y down, Z far (optical axis)."* there is no world frame.

Comment: Again, we seem to misunderstand each other, and I am failing to understand where that misunderstanding is coming from. The whole point of doing an extrinsic calibration is to locate the camera in 3D space, i.e. do define a transformation from camera space (what you just described) to world-(or object-)space, right? That's why there is a translation vector `tvec` that describes the camera location and a rotation vector `rvec` that describes the camera rotation?

Comment: I can't really understand what is problem.
I believe that, In general, if the rotation is representing relationship between 2 coordinate-systems... when rotation is zero, axis direction of the both coordinate-systems is same (because there is no relative rotation).

Comment: crossposted: https://forum.opencv.org/t/what-is-the-reference-vector-in-opencv-for-3d-rotation/14757

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think that I finally have something that seems right.
I'll try to summarize my findings as an answer here, but I'm still ordering my thoughts as I'm writing this, so forgive me if this answer is still a little unclear.

As @fana and @ChristophRackwitz pointed out, there is an object coordinate system and there is a camera coordinate system.
The object coordinate system is a regular, right-handed cartesian coordinate system, so with X and Y defining the horizontal plane and Z pointing upwards.
As @ChristophRackwitz described, the camera coordinate system is attached to the camera's projection plane.
When looking through the camera's lens, X is pointing to the right, Y is pointing down and Z is pointing outwards.
So, in my own words, `v_Cam` is equal to the Z-axis in the camera coordinate system.

[This website](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT9/node2.html) has a good illustration of the coordinate systems.

Furthermore, as @fana said, if no translation and no rotation is applied (i.e., the rotation matrix is an identity matrix or the Rodrigues vector is all zeros), the axis of the object coordinate system and the camera coordinate system are the same.

So, if my understanding is correct, the following applies:
When no rotation is applied, the coordinate axis are the same.
Thus, `v_cam` is equal to the Z-axis of the object coordinate system in this case, which would also mean that `v_Ref = (0, 0, 1)` (aligned with the Z-axis of the object coordinate system).

With this in mind, I started experimenting:
I generated myself an 11-by-11 grid of planar object points:

```kotlin
val objectPoints = List(11) { rowIndex ->
    List(11) { columnIndex ->
        Point3(columnIndex.toDouble() - 5.0, rowIndex.toDouble() - 5.0, 0.0)
    }
}.flatten()
```

(This code generates a regular grid of points going from `(-5.0, -5.0, 0.0)` to `(5.0, 5.0, 0.0)`

[image: Visualization of the situation in object space]

I then wanted my camera to be above those planar object points, pointing downwards (c.f., `v_cam` in the figure above), and generated the projected image points accordingly:

```kotlin
val imagePoints = List(11) { rowIndex ->
    List(11) { columnIndex ->
        Point((columnIndex.toDouble() - 5.0) * imageScaleFactor, (rowIndex.toDouble() - 5.0) * imageScaleFactor)
    }
}.flatten()
```

[image: Points projected into the image plane]

I then proceeded to call `Calib3d.calibrateCamera()` with those points as the input:

```kotlin
val cameraMatrix = Mat()
val distortionCoefficients = Mat()
val rotationVectors = mutableListOf<Mat>()
val translationVectors = mutableListOf<Mat>()

val overallRms = Calib3d.calibrateCamera(
    // The map and toMat-functions just convert the data into a form that OpenCV accepts
    listOf(objectPoints.map { it.toOpenCVPoint() }.toMat3f()),
    listOf(imagePoints.toMat2f()),
    imageSize,
    cameraMatrix,
    distortionCoefficients,
    rotationVectors,
    translationVectors
)
```

Which gave me the following intrinsics:

```kotlin
CameraIntrinsics(
    cameraMatrix = CameraMatrix(
        focalLength = Point(x = 1.350310986449413E17, y = 1.3503109864494126E17),
        opticalCenter = Point(x = 9.500000000000115, y = 9.500000000000115)
    ),
    distortionCoefficients = DistortionCoefficients(
        k1 = -1.2551867374857695E-26,
        k2 = -3.1640690574535313E-41,
        p1 = 1.4867968141433821E-6,
        p2 = 1.4867967882740299E-6,
        k3 = -9.212409017493725E-56,
    ),
    overallRms = 3.7999673703527265E9
)
```

and extrinsics:

```kotlin
CameraExtrinsics(
    worldLocation = Point3(x = -7.905761924365692E-9, y = -7.905762033403558E-9, z = 1.123709191949999E8),
    rotation = RodriguesVector(-1.110720731360427, 1.1107207365421794, -3.6640522551246774E-9)
)
```

At first, the Rodrigues vector looked like what I was expecting:
The camera is pointing straight down, so the camera's z-axis (or `v_cam`) is in the exact opposite direction of the object coordinate system's z-axis (or what I believed to be `v_Ref`).
Therefore, I expected `v_Rodrigues` to be in the X-Y-plane, since it has to be perpendicular to both, `v_Cam` and `v_Ref`. However, I expected the length of the Rodrigues vector to be `3.1415 [rad] = 180°` since `v_cam` is pointing down whereas I assumed `v_Ref` to be equal to the z-axis, thus pointing up, resulting in a 180° angle between the two.

This, however, was not the case:
If you calculate the length of the above Rodrigues vector, it turns out to be `pi/2 [rad] = 90°`, not `180°`.

Since OpenCV calculated a reasonable translation vector, I assumed that the Rodrigues vector was correct as well, just not what I expected.
However, given that I know that the camera is pointing down, I could apply the Rodrigues formula in reverse (i.e. multiplying the Rodrigues vector by `-1` and then applying the formula as mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Statement)), giving me the true `v_Ref`.

And as it turns out, `v_Ref` seems to be `(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)`.

I don't yet have a logical explanation as to why this can be, but testing some other camera positions seems to confirm that as well.
I will now proceed with my project under the assumption that `v_Ref = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)` and update this answer as I find more.

Thank you to @fana and @ChristophRackwitz for bearing with me :)

Comment: `overallRms = 3.7999673703527265E9` looks like very large. (It may indicate some ploblem.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `calibrateCamera()`, but... your `imagePoints` seems strange.
This is saying that, the central point of the your gird `(X,Y,Z)=(0,0,0)` is projected to top-left pixel `(x,y)=(0,0)` on the camera image. i.e. only 1/4 of the grid is included in camera FOV.

Comment: Therefore, for this input, OpenCV should decide some plausible move of pattern plate. When I think very very simply, it may become as `t = (-6, -6, some plus value)`. (the your `worldLocation` is not so far form this?).
For rotation, I can't estimate why such large result was calculated... but as already said, from the large RMS value, I can estimate that process colud not find good answer.

Comment: If you are showing the output extrinsic parameter values from `calibrateCamera()`  as "CameraExtrinsics" as is, it is wrong.
They are **of pattern**.

Comment: Oh, you are very right with the `imagePoints being outsiode of the image`. I imagine that is what is causing the high RMS. Let me fix that...

Comment: Concerning the "of pattern": The OpenCV docs say "In more technical terms, the tuple of the i-th rotation and translation vector performs a change of basis from object coordinate space to camera coordinate space. Due to its duality, this tuple is equivalent to the position of the calibration pattern with respect to the camera coordinate space. " I understood this sentence such that this is both? But thinking about it, this seems wrong indeed....

Comment: I repeated the experiment with all `imagePoints` being positive, but the results just keep getting weirder (the RMS is now 1e8...). I guess I have to do some more debugging and will post the updated results once I figured out what's wrong ^^